# parsing iPhone App Store RSS XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, app-store, review

I am having a tough time parsing App Store xml to pull out the rating(s) for an appID.(appID is 298307011)

XML: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=298307011/xml

The rating I am trying to pull out for each of the app review entry is . The tree structure is root > entry -> im:rating

My code is not fetching the rating text.

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=298307011/xml'

xml_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)


for rating in root.iter('im:rating'):
    print rating.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add the namespace and using something besides `iter`

Using lmxl and xpath:

```
import urllib2
import lxml.etree as etree
url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=298307011/xml'

xml_string = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
root = etree.fromstring(xml_string)


for rating in root.xpath('//im:rating', namespaces={'im':'http://itunes.apple.com/rss'}):
    print rating.text
```

Comment: It worked. lxml is new to me and it looks like a powerful tool to know. Thank you.

Comment: @JoGeo cool! please [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and accept the answer if you found it useful :)